# print html list from scanned directory including sub directories php

Tags: php, list, recursion

I am trying to create a navigation list from a scanned directory including sub directories.
What I would like is a nav list that will include the file. Also when a directory is clicked to include a custom directory file.

Here is what I have achieved.

1) Use a recursive function to scan directory and sub directories and print a html list.

2) Use a recursive function to scan directory and sub directories to get path to files.

3) request page variable and match page value with name value and then inc path to files.

Problems I have encountered.

1) I cannot determine what is a directory and what is a file from returned array

2) I cannot control the page error file from within the loop - returns multiple 404s.

# select directory
    $dir = 'pages';

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
  $files = scandir($dir);
# place value home in first position of array
  $home = 'home.php';
  $search_home = array_search($home, $files);
  if ($search_home > 0) {
    unset($files[$search_home]);
    array_unshift($files, $home);
  }

  echo "<ul class='cf nav nav--horiz'>";

  foreach($files as $file){
  # remove extension from files
    $parts = pathinfo($file);
    $name  = $parts['filename'];
  # remove underscore from file name and replace with space.
    $search = array('_' ,'-');
    $replace = " ";
    $str_name = str_replace($search, $replace, $name);

    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
      echo '<li>'.'<a href="?page='.$name.'">'.$str_name.'</a>';
      if(is_dir("$dir/$file")){ listFolderFiles("$dir/$file"); }
      echo "</li>";
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
} # end function

function find_all_files($dir) {
  $root = scandir($dir);

  foreach($root as $value) {
    if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;}
    if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result[]="$dir/$value";continue;}
    foreach(find_all_files("$dir/$value") as $value){
      $result[]=$value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
} # end function 

# call the function and print inside nav
  echo "<nav class='navBar'>";
    listFolderFiles($dir);
  echo "</nav>";

# call the function and pass the result to array
  $allFiles = find_all_files($dir);

# check the query string to see if page is set
  $page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : '';

# loop through and match the page var with array value
  foreach ($allFiles as $file) {
# remove extension from files
  $parts = pathinfo($file);
  $name  = $parts['filename'];
  if($page == $name) {
    include($file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator` class](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). It may help you. And I would not iterate trough all dir entries and store them first in an array and then loop trough the array again. Just do all the stuff right during the first iteration so you have all needed information at that point.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the duplication when creating the list but I am not sure how to create the nested list from a returned array. The recursive function targets the sub dirs in the loop and wraps a <ul> inside the <li>. When working with a returned multi dimensional array I do not have the ability to test with is_dir??? Or should I test with is_array as assumption can be made that is_dir will generate a new array.